# React native, creating buttons in for loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to get some data from API of eventbrite.

The data is event's name, and the name will be inserted into the list.

In render, buttons are created as many as the number of name which I got from API

I have got few questions below..

1. How to add information from API into array list - so I can use index, and value.
2. How to create buttons in forloop

e.g.

```
for ( var i =0; i<5; i++){
 <Button
 onPress={onPressLearnMore}
 title="Learn More"
 color="#841584"
 accessibilityLabel="Learn more about this purple button"/>
} // % buttons are created.
```

This is my code.

```
 export const renderButtons1 = (numOfBtns,title,site,navigated) => {
    const views1 = [];
    for ( var i = 0; i < numOfBtns; i++) {
            views1.push(
            <Button 
                 onPress={(i) => navigate('EventsList', { 
                     Title: title[i]
                })
            }
                 title = {title[i]}
                 color="#841584"
             />);


    }
componentDidMount(){
return fetch('https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/search/location.address=glasgow&token=F7AWKEHKD6BW2TZKWO7N&expand=venue')
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseJson) => {   
      for(var x in responseJson.events){       
          this.setState({
              state : this.state[Events].push(responseJson.events[x][0][0]["text"],"\n",)
 });
}})
.catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
});
}

render() {
        need to make buttons as many as the number of gotten name from API 
}
```

Comment: when you need to return something from a loop, you would usually use the [`Array.prototype.map` ](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). `collection.map(b => <Button ... />)`

Comment: I tried to put render() { var array1 = [1, 4, 9, 16]; array1.map(b => <Button ... />) } it does not work, I wanted to put button into inside of <view> which I can't do - the buttons are always in <view>

Comment: _"it does not work"_ - what exactly not working?

Comment: well, it is does not create ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. For question 1, array form of api data will depend on how the data is structured before being sent to your application. You may have to shade more light on that.
2. Rendering views in a loop, try that

   ```
   const renderButtons = () => {
   const views = [];
   for ( var i =0; i<5; i++){
    views.push(
       <Button
          key={i}
          onPress={onPressLearnMore}
          title="Learn More"
          color="#841584"
          accessibilityLabel="Learn more about this purple button"
       />);
   } // % buttons are created. 

   return views;
   }
   ```

call `renderButtons()` in your render methods.

Comment: and the api is https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/search/location.address=glasgow&token=F7AWKEHKD6BW2TZKWO7N&expand=venue

Comment: just wondering why the key value is not fixed. so, when I clicked a first button key values is 5, then when I clicked the first button again the key value 6 increasing by 1

Comment: do you how to get fixed key.. ?

Comment: Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed. Keys should be given to the elements inside the array to give the elements a stable identity check [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)

Comment: I am looking for the way of using views's index, so when you click the first button which is index 0, then the array's value which is index 0 will be retired. how would I store only the index..

Comment: Title: title[i] is not working... well I probably need the index

Comment: I think you post another question for that issue and you get more help